# weka DBSCAN clustering, how to get the core point

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan

I am using DBSCAN to cluster the data, after clustering, for each cluster I want to get the data attribute value of the core point, is there a way to do this?

```
 private static void ClusteringDemo(String filename) throws Exception {
    ClusterEvaluation eval;
    Instances  data;
    DBSCAN cl;
    data = DataSource.read(filename);

    // manual call
    cl  = new DBSCAN();
    cl.setMinPoints(6);
    cl.setEpsilon(0.05);
    cl.buildClusterer(data);
    eval = new ClusterEvaluation();
    eval.setClusterer(cl);
    eval.evaluateClusterer(new Instances(data));
    System.out.println(eval.clusterResultsToString());

    //setup visualization
    PlotData2D predData = ClustererPanel.setUpVisualizableInstances(data, eval);
    VisualizePanel vp = new VisualizePanel();
    vp.addPlot(predData);

    // display data
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Weka Clusterer Visualize: " + vp.getName());
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(500, 400);
    jf.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jf.getContentPane().add(vp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

cl is the DBSCAN class, and I only implement the visualization. Anyone could teach me how to get the core point value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "the core point value".

DBSCAN does *not* use cluster centers like k-mean does.

[Consider this DBSCAN image (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DBSCAN-density-data.svg). Where would "the core point value" of the red cluster be?

Clusters can be arbitrary shaped, and then there is no "center". In fact the average of all points may be outside of the cluster.

A cluster has at least one core point, but there may be many more - all of them could be core points at the same time. Thus, the information which points are core points is not very important. If I recall correctly, ELKI has an option to expose this information, but by default it is discarded immediately.